# What does TouchDevice.Capture() actually do in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

I can't seem to find any real documentation on what `TouchDevice.Capture()` really does. When and / or how should I use it? Or where can I  read more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It captures touch input for the specified IInputElement, in the same way as mouse input is captured (see the Remarks in [MouseDevice.Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousedevice.capture.aspx)).

When touch input is captured, the element continues to receive touch events even if the touch position lies outside the hit test area of the element.

You may try the example code in [TouchDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touchdevice.aspx) with and without capture and observe the different behaviour.